# How don't i apply css of jquery mobile to specific elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

How don't i apply css of jquery mobile to specific elements?

Isn't there any way to do this without modifying the css file of jquery mobile?

plz help me.

Comment: you override styles for specific elements in a separate stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the appropriate style class or id, using the `class=""` or `div=""` attributes. Without knowing what you're trying to do that is all the specificity I can provide.

Comment: i mean, i don't want to apply basic css of jquery mobile to specific elements.

Comment: Ah I see, apologies. In that case you either have to override the CSS with your own, or edit the jquery's CSS. Another way would be to use different id or class names than what jquery uses (unless it's on default elements, in that case you cannot do this).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:
1. Create your own stylesheet and add your styles. For instance if jquery mobile has a .button element you can define it yourself and enter the overriding properties by writing your own .button as in

```
.button {
 background-color: #ccc;
}
```

You then HAVE TO load this stylesheet last when you are loading stylesheets. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Notice that your stylesheet comes last.

2.You can include overriding styles into the element itself using the style attribute. This is not good practice but helps with some specificity issues. 
example:

```
<button class="jquery-button" style="background-color: #ccc" > Button </button>
```

3.You can use !important if all else fails but really try to avoid this because it will make maintaining your code harder and it will take a long time to troubleshoot it later, besides it doesn't always work anyway.
example:

```
.button {
background-color: #ccc !important;
}
```

Check out this article : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Or maybe what you are looking for is something like the :not selector, though cross-browser compatibility is a potential issue:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just use **data-role='none'** on that element